# Host header Injection in Apache2.4

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have configured apache server
following is content of my conf files:
websitename.conf file:

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@trmapps
ServerName xyz.somedomain.com
ServerAlias somedomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/databridge/public_html
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!RSA:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384

```
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/ga2022.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/ga.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/certs/ga-gd2022.crt
```

<Directory /home/databridge/public_html>
Options -Indexes
allow from all
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

Header always set X-Frame-options SAMEORIGIN
    Header unset server
    Header unset X-Forwarded-Host
    Header always unset X-Forwarded-By
    Header unset X-Powered-By
    Header unset X-CF-Powered-By
    Header unset X-Mod-Pagespeed
    Header unset X-Pingback

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'somedomain.com'">
deny from all

The application is running fine. But if we change the host header and send request to my server (let's say if we change host header to bing.com), then also my server is responding to that request and redirecting to bing.com.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !xyz.somedomain.com
RewriteRule ^.(.*) - [L,F]

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'xyz.somedomain.com'">
Deny from all

None of them is working. Apache version is 2.4.41